# Where does JSS write dynamic MaterialUI classes?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

In my application, I am using Material UI. I can see most of the classes added to the head tag, but I cannot find my own custom styles.

When I use MuiBox and change the order property dynamically, a random class name is generated, and styles are applied correctly. However, I need to get that CSS for processing my view as a PDF using the complete HTML and CSS. When I click the `<style>` link in Chrome dev tools for my custom styles (top-right circle in the first screenshot below), the style tag it shows me in the `<head>` (second screenshot) is empty. Since my styles are applied correctly, I know the style tag is there somewhere. But where is it?

[image]

[image]

Is there any JSS plugin that can help to read those dynamic styles?

Comment: From your comments, I'm not sure I can really help without seeing your app in person or a codesandbox or something, so I just deleted my answer. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I have added the point that I got to empty tags when I clicked on the style tag on the dev tools.